# Beginner's snake game in pygame

Tags: python, beginner, pygame, snake-game

This is the first big project for me and I am not sure which is the correct way to structure the code yet. Is it okay to have so many classes and functions? What else should I improve?

````py
import pygame
import sys
import random


pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Monospace', 35)

# COLORS
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (32, 238, 189)
YELLOW = (255, 230, 0)
RED = (250, 25, 78)
GREEN2 = (33, 239, 33)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# SCREEN
TILE_SIZE = 30
GRID_SIZE = [40, 30]
FPS = 20
WIDTH = GRID_SIZE[0] * TILE_SIZE
HEIGHT = GRID_SIZE[1] * TILE_SIZE
BACKGROUND_COLOR = BLACK
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

score = 0


class BodyPart:

    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        self.dir_x, self.dir_y = direction
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def set_direction(self, direction):
        self.dir_x = direction[0]
        self.dir_y = direction[1]


class Snake:

    def __init__(self):
        self.color = GREEN
        self.body = [BodyPart(TILE_SIZE * 3, int(HEIGHT / 2), (1, 0))]

    def append_body_part(self, count):
        for i in range(count):
            x, y, dir_x, dir_y = self.body[-1].x, self.body[-1].y, self.body[-1].dir_x, self.body[-1].dir_y
            x -= dir_x * TILE_SIZE
            y -= dir_y * TILE_SIZE
            self.body.append(BodyPart(x, y, (dir_x, dir_y)))

    def update_position(self):
        for body_part in self.body:
            body_part.x += body_part.dir_x * TILE_SIZE
            body_part.y += body_part.dir_y * TILE_SIZE
        z = len(self.body) - 1
        while z != 0:
            self.body[z].dir_x = self.body[z-1].dir_x
            self.body[z].dir_y = self.body[z-1].dir_y
            z -= 1

    def collision(self):
        head_x, head_y = self.body[0].x, self.body[0].y
        for body_part in snake.body[1:]:
            if body_part.x == head_x and body_part.y == head_y:
                    return True
        if head_x < 0 or head_x == WIDTH or head_y < 0 or head_y == HEIGHT:
            return True
        return False


class Food:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None
        self.length_bonus = None
        self.color = None
        self.__random_coords()
        self.__choose_random_food()

    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))

    def eaten(self):
        return (snake.body[0].x, snake.body[0].y) == (self.x, self.y)

    def __random_coords(self):
        matching = True
        while matching:
            self.x = random.randrange(TILE_SIZE, WIDTH - TILE_SIZE + 1, TILE_SIZE)
            self.y = random.randrange(TILE_SIZE, HEIGHT - TILE_SIZE + 1, TILE_SIZE)
            for body_part in snake.body:
                if self.x != body_part.x and self.y != body_part.y:
                    matching = False

    def __choose_random_food(self):
        self.foods = [self.__banana, self.__apple, self.__watermelon]
        random.choice(self.foods)()

    def __banana(self):
        self.length_bonus = 1
        self.color = YELLOW

    def __apple(self):
        self.length_bonus = 2
        self.color = RED

    def __watermelon(self):
        self.length_bonus = 3
        self.color = GREEN2


def redraw_screen():
    global food_on_screen, food, score
    screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    for body_part in snake.body:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, snake.color, (body_part.x, body_part.y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
    if not food_on_screen:
        food = Food()
        food_on_screen = True
    food.display()
    if food.eaten():
        snake.append_body_part(food.length_bonus)
        score += food.length_bonus
        food_on_screen = False
    text = font.render(f"Score: {score}", False, WHITE)
    screen.blit(text, (TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE))
    pygame.display.update()


snake = Snake()
food_on_screen = False
game_over = False

while not game_over:

    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and snake.body[0].dir_x != -1:
                snake.body[0].set_direction([1, 0])
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and snake.body[0].dir_x != 1:
                snake.body[0].set_direction([-1, 0])
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP and snake.body[0].dir_y != 1:
                snake.body[0].set_direction([0, -1])
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and snake.body[0].dir_y != -1:
                snake.body[0].set_direction([0, 1])

    snake.update_position()

    if snake.collision():
        game_over = True
        break

    redraw_screen()

print(f"Your final score: {score}")


```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, from an Object-Oriented perspective, you have objects that represent real objects within the game with behaviors and attributes, so on that note, well done! There are, however, other areas that need a bit of TLC.

You have an enumeration of colors sitting there as individually-defined constants. For a bit more type-safety, I would suggest persisting them in an [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instead:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
    # other
    # colors
    # here
```

You can then access the enum constant for the color black as `Color.BLACK` and the tuple of RGB values as `Color.BLACK.value`.

Moving on to something a bit more functional, it doesn't make sense that each `BodyPart` has a direction. Conceptually speaking, the only thing in the game Snake that has a direction is the head, and each body part occupies the space of the body part in front of it per game tick.

I would suggest removing direction entirely from `BodyPart`, and storing the `BodyPart` objects within `Snake` as a **linked list**. Because in the end, you can still iterate through each `BodyPart`, but considering the 3 most important features:

- The **head**, and its directional movement
- The **link between each `BodyPart` and the next**, to determine movement of the `BodyPart`s
- The **tail**, for adding new `BodyPart`s to the `Snake`

The linked list is the most meaningful data structure to use here.

Also, `Food` is a bit weird. Actually initializing a `Food` object is hidden behind private methods, which makes no logical sense. `Food` initialization should require parameters to define what type of food it is and where it is on the game. We can revisit the idea of enums and introduce a `FoodType` enum of tuples of form `(length_bonus, Color)` where we can once again use our `Color` enum from before, then require a `FoodType` parameter in init along with x and y. Then we can move the methods that generate a random Color and position out of that class and use those to generate the necessities for a Food object.

Lastly, I would highly recommend encapsulating x and y in all cases into a Point object. That would make it much easier to keep track of each piece's coordinates, and subsequently movements, collisions, etc.

```py
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    # __eq__ and other important methods here
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. But there is one thing that I don't understand. Why do I need to store my color constants in a class which inherits from Enum? To access a color I now need to say Color.BLACK.value instead of just BLACK which makes it more complicated. What is the purpouse of this?

Comment: Several reasons, which allude to the capabilities of the Enum type. The reason I gave first was type safety: you can check if parameters are Colors since `Color` is a declared class now. Enums are also iterable, flexible, hashable, and more efficiently interpreted. Follow the link in my answer to the documentation for Enum, you'll see more advantages.